# Is there a canonical behavior for the behavior of an object that would have its weight/mass reduced below 0?

Tags: spells, anima-beyond-fantasy, weight

There is a level 10 spell in the Path of Air that "reduces the weight of an object by 60 pounds" (+20 lbs per added effect).

What happens (or should happen) if you cast this spell on an object that weighs, e.g., 59 lbs?

As a side note: the thing being reduced may actually be mass, given that the corresponding Weight Increment (Earth 10) spell uses as its unit the kilogram.  Consider this interpretation as well.

Comment: Note: All answers should be supported by relevant evidence from *Anima: Beyond Fantasy*. The question is not asking about real-world physics. Unless the answer demonstrates that *Anima* does not canonically address this situation, such answers solely citing real-world physics (theoretical or otherwise) will be deleted. (Questions answering solely based on material from unrelated RPG systems will also be deleted.)

Comment: Note on the note: I'm 90% sure there's not any rules text that covers this, but I'm not ruling out something existing in, e.g., the Spanish-language version of the core rules, or something I missed (out of the core rules and the Prometheum, Dominus, and Arcana Exxets - but *not* Core Exxet) that would clarify things.

Comment: @Riddley: [Don't answer in comments.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments) You're welcome to leave that as an answer instead.

Comment: Related metas: [What is an acceptable form for a “no” answer to a question of the form “Does X exist in the lore?”](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8265/33569), [What To Do When There Are No Right Answers, Only Wrong Ones](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8033/33569), [Whether to answer or not if one believes there is no answer possible](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5530/33569)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can say with reasonable certainty that there is no specific ruling on this in the book. Anything said here on the subject would be a house rule by the GM, or agreed upon by your Party.

Here's how I handled it.

I ran a campaign based in a weightless but air filled environment, where there was no gravity except made by magic, or by using centrifugal force. What I determined was the objects could not have negative mass, because physics does some seriously weird things when that happens(Source needed).

Objects with near zero mass would behave very similar to how light does, and time would probably be a bit wonky as well.

It basically boiled down to: OK. You can be weightless, but it also means that the only thing slowing you down once you get going will be air resistance.

The inverse essentially multiplied the damage associated with falling, and also made it rather hard to move (If not explicitly impossible) for low strength characters.

Bottom line is. This is a question entirely based on your GM's interpretation, and how much physics they care to bother with.

TLDR; The answer is, as far as I can tell that there isn't a definitive ruling on it. If it could be found in any of the books, I would look for it in the GM's book, or the extended combat rules in the Dominus Exxet. Neither of which it can be found in. I have read the Core Exxet, and can say that there are no mentions of anything remotely like this.